# Form a Matrix From a Large Text File Quickly

Tags: algorithm, matlab, file-io, matrix

Hi I am struggling with reading data from a file quickly enough. ( Currently left for 4hrs, then crashed) must be a  simpler way.

The text file looks similar like this:

```
From To
1    5
3    2
2    1
4    3
```

From this I want to form a matrix so that there is a 1 in the according [m,n]

The current code is:

```
    function [z] = reed (A)

    [m,n]=size(A);
    i=1;

    while (i <= n)
        z(A(1,i),A(2,i))=1;
        i=i+1;
    end
```

Which output the following matrix, z:

```
    z =

 0     0     0     0     1
 1     0     0     0     0
 0     1     0     0     0
 0     0     1     0     0
```

My actual file has 280,000,000 links to and from, this code is too slow for this size file. Does anybody know a much faster was to do this in matlab?

thanks

Comment: Did you try textscan ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do something along the lines of the following:

```
>> A = zeros(4,5);
>> B = importdata('testcase.txt');
>> A(sub2ind(size(A),B.data(:,1),B.data(:,2))) = 1;
```

My test case, `'testcase.txt'` contains your sample data:

```
From To
1    5
3    2
2    1
4    3
```

The result would be:

```
>> A

A =

     0     0     0     0     1
     1     0     0     0     0
     0     1     0     0     0
     0     0     1     0     0
```

### EDIT - 1

After taking a look at your data, it seems that even if you modify this code appropriately, you may not have enough memory to execute it as the matrix `A` would become too large.

As such, you can use `sparse` matrices to achieve the same as given below:

```
>> B = importdata('web-Stanford.txt');
>> A = sparse(B.data(:,1),B.data(:,2),1,max(max(B.data)),max(max(B.data)));
```

This would be the approach I'd recommend as your `A` matrix will have a size of `[281903,281903]` which would usually be too large to handle due to memory constraints. A `sparse` matrix on the other hand, maintains only those matrix entries which are non-zero, thus saving on a lot of space. In most cases, you can use sparse matrices more-or-less as you use normal matrices.

More information about the `sparse` command is given [here](http://www.mathworks.in/help/matlab/ref/sparse.html).

### EDIT - 2

I'm not sure why it isn't working for you. Here's a screenshot of how I did it in case that helps:

[image]

### EDIT - 3

It seems that you're getting a `double` matrix in `B` while I'm getting a `struct`. I'm not sure why this is happening; I can only speculate that you deleted the header lines from the input file before you used `importdata`.

Basically it's just that my `B.data` is the same as your `B`. As such, you should be able to use the following instead:

```
>> A = sparse(B(:,1),B(:,2),1,max(max(B)),max(max(B)));
```

Comment: what does `sub2ind` actually do ?

Comment: @noufal: It converts the subscripts to linear indices. For example, for the matrix `A` of `4` rows and `5` columns, since MATLAB stores data in column major form, `A(1,1)` is the same as `A(1)`, `A(2,1)` is the same as `A(2)`, `A(1,2)` is the same as `A(5)` and so on.

Comment: Hi, that doesnt work roney:Attempt to reference field of non-structure array.

Error in ==> read at 5
A(sub2ind(size(A),B.data(:,1),B.data(:,2))) = 1;

Comment: It needs to be a square matix, which represents the link structure of the file, not a (4,5) matrix roney. I dont know exactly how big it it but around 2.8m.

Comment: Attempt to reference field of non-structure array. Error in ==> read at 5 A(sub2ind(size(A),B.data(:,1),B.data(:,2))) = 1

Comment: @ElleElle: Can you provide the data file? It's difficult to get what you mean with only the sample data to work with.

Comment: Here is a link to the file (8mb) http://snap.stanford.edu/data/web-Stanford.txt.gz

Comment: @RoneyMichael: Get this error -> Attempt to reference field of non-structure array

Comment: @RoneyMichael: Hi roney, I have done exactly what you say in edit and it doesnt work.(error=Attempt to reference field of non-structure array) Have you tried it and got it working? Thanks

Comment: @Parag What am i doing wrong if i copy it exactly? running on r2011a maci64

Comment: @ElleElle: It works perfectly for me. I've put in a screenshot as well in case it helps.

Comment: @ElleElle: Can you put in a screenshot of what you got?

Comment: @RoneyMichael: This is a screen shot of what is happening [IMG]http://i38.tinypic.com/2hgqv5f.png[/IMG]

Comment: @ElleElle: Great. :) Do accept the answer if you're satisfied with it. This marks your question as solved and may benefit the community in the future.

Comment: @ElleElle: Just out of curiosity, had you deleted the header lines from the input file before you used `importdata`? If so, that's the reason you got a `double` matrix and not a `struct` in `B`.